# SBT User limit of inotify instances reached or too many open files

Tags: java, docker, scala, sbt

I have cloned [AWS Code Build](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images.git) REPO.

when I try to build

```
 => ERROR [runtimes_n_corretto 4/6] RUN sbt version -Dsbt.rootdir=true                                      14.6s
------
 > [runtimes_n_corretto 4/6] RUN sbt version -Dsbt.rootdir=true:
0.578 copying runtime jar...
5.095 [info] [launcher] getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.6.2  (this may take some time)...
10.28 [info] [launcher] getting Scala 2.12.15 (for sbt)...
11.28 [info] Updated file /project/build.properties: set sbt.version to 1.6.2
11.29 [info] welcome to sbt 1.6.2 (Amazon.com Inc. Java 11.0.20.1)
12.42 [info] loading project definition from /project
14.01 [info] set current project to root (in build file:/)
14.02 java.io.IOException: User limit of inotify instances reached or too many open files
....

    Dockerfile:414
    --------------------
     412 |     
     413 |     ENV PATH "/usr/local/bin/sbt/bin:$PATH"
     414 | >>> RUN sbt version -Dsbt.rootdir=true
     415 |     # Cleanup
     416 |     RUN rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    --------------------
    ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c sbt version -Dsbt.rootdir=true" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

sbt lines in Dockerfile

```
ENV PATH "/usr/local/bin/sbt/bin:$PATH"
RUN sbt version -Dsbt.rootdir=true
```

`sbt version` shows

```
[warn] No sbt.version set in project/build.properties, base directory: /home/miki/aws-codebuild-docker-images/ubuntu/standard/5.0
[info] welcome to sbt 1.9.4 (Ubuntu Java 11.0.20)
[info] set current project to root-5-0 (in build file:/home/miki/aws-codebuild-docker-images/ubuntu/standard/5.0/
[info] 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using:

```
echo 256 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
```